# What is wrong in this proof of all subsets of compact sets are compact?

Tags: general-topology

I read the theorem that any closed subset of compact set is compact. But, in this proof, all subsets of compact set appear to be compact. So where has this gone wrong?

Claim:Let $A\subset B\subset X$ where $B$ is compact set in $X$. Then $A$ is also compact.

Proof:Given that $B$ is compact in $X$ then any open cover of $B$, there is a finite open subcover, denote it as $\left \{V_i  \right \}_{i=1}^{N}$. Since $A\subset B\subset \left \{V_i  \right \}_{i=1}^{N}$ so $A\subset\left \{V_i\cap A  \right \}_{i=1}^{N}$ and so $\left \{V_i\cap A  \right \}_{i=1}^{N}$covers $A$ and hence $A$ is compact in $X$

Comment: You have to test for all open covers of $A$. Notice that in general an open cover of $A$ need not be an open cover of $B$. For instance, consider $A=(0,1)\subset[0,1]=B$ and the open cover $\{(1/n,1-1/n):n\geq 3\}$ of $A$.

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake is in that not every open cover of $A$ is an open cover of $B$. Those open covers of $A$ that happen to also be open covers of $B$ indeed have finite subcovers of $B$, which then are also finite subcovers of $A$. But there are in general open covers of $A$ that are not open covers of $B$, and there's no reason why those should have an finite subcover of $A$ (they certainly don't have a subcover that covers $B$, finite or otherwise).

For example, consider the set $A=\{\frac12,\frac14,\frac16,\ldots\}$, which is a subset of the compact set $B=[0,1]$ in the topological space $X=\mathbb R$ with the usual topology. Clearly $A$ is covered by $C=\{(\frac13,1),(\frac15,\frac13),(\frac17,\frac15),\ldots\}$, but not by any subcover. This does not contradict the compactness of $[0,1]$ because $C$ does not cover the set $[0,1]$ (because e.g. $\frac13\in[0,1]$ but there's no element of $C$ that  contains $\frac13$).

Comment: But, don't we take open subsets as open coverings. But, elements of $C$ in this example doesn't belong to set $A$, so they are not open in $A$ ? I am little confused here.

Comment: The OP never states or use that every open cover of $A$ is an open cover of $B$.

Comment: @AloknathFurr: The elements of $C$ are open subsets in $\mathbb R$ (and in $\mathbb [0,1]$). To get the corresponding open subsets in $A$ you have to intersect it with $A$. Of course this gives the individual points of $A$ (the induced topology on $A$ is the discrete topology), and it has a finite subcover iff $C$ has a finite subcover.

Comment: @egreg: The OP may not explicitly state it, but implicitly assumes it when speaking about covers of $B$ when determining the compactness of $A$.

Comment: @celtschk this is not true. What is assumed is that every cover of $A$ arises as a subcover of $B$, which is not true.

Comment: @AndresMejia: Of course every cover of $A$ arises as a subcover of some cover of $B$. Just add a single open set covering all of $B$, and then you've got a cover of $B$ that has the cover of $A$ as subcover.

Comment: @AndresMejia: The open cover of $A$, when looking at $A$ as space with subspace topology, actually *does* have that form (indeed, *all* open sets in $A$ are, by definition, intersections of open sets in $X$ with $A$).

Answer (score 2):

In order to show $A$ is compact you have to start with an arbitrary open cover of $A$ and prove it has a finite subcover. The fact that open covers of $A$ induced by open covers of $B$ have a finite subcover is not sufficient.

For an easy counterexample, consider $A=(0,1]$ and $B=[0,1]$. Then the sets
$$
U_n=(1/n,1]
$$
form an open cover of $A$ that cannot be obtained in the form $V_n\cap A$, where the sets $V_n$ form an open cover of $B$.

Comment: Can we take open cover of A, which is not itself open in A. For example you took U_n=(1/n,2) which doesn't lie inside A.

Comment: @AloknathFurr Changed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to start from a cover of $A$ and prove that there is a finite subcover. This cover may not cover all of $B$. Now, it is easy to add more sets to get a cover of $B$, which will then have a finite subcover ($B$ - compact), which will even cover $A$ (as a subset of $B$) - but it will be impossible to prove that it can be further reduced to *only* the elements from the original cover (i.e. not need to have some of the sets from the addendum we introduced when we made the cover of $B$).

If $A$ is closed in $B$, then the argument goes further, because $B\setminus A$ is open in $B$, i.e. it can be added without fear that it will be later needed in the finite subcover of $A$, namely it is disjoint with $A$ and can later be thrown away.